# Css transition height does not work using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here is the problem i want to make a dropdown for my website using javascript but the transition of height doesn't work , when i click the on the div i made it doesnt transition well it works it sets the height to auto and it shows a way but the problem is it doesnt transition so its not smooth , it just pop out. please help and thank you in advance mates.

Here are the codes:

the HTML

```
<h1 id="btnh" onClick="show_about('aboutcr')">about</h1>

<div id="aboutcr">
    <div id="pcontcr">
        <p id="p2r">"Hey guys my name is <span>Vincent Nocum</span> and welcome to my project     website. I'm a 17yrs old student taking up <span>Information Technology Course in Lyceum of The Philippines Laguna</span>, The purpose of this website is for my project in <span>Communication Arts II</span> lead by our professor <span>Ms.Lenie De Leon</span>. I post some topic on this website held by our professor. So its concluded that this website is only for educational purposes only"</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the css

```
    #aboutcr{
        display: inline-block;
        background:white;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: justify;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0px;
        transition: height .5s;
        -webkit-transition: height .5s;
        -moz-transition: height .5s;
        -ms-transition: height .5s;
        -o-transition: height .5s;
    }

    #btnh {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: latolight;
        /*text-transform: capitalize;*/
        font-size: 25px;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        color: #9bcf40;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: #9bcf40;
        margin-top: -4px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1 );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1 );
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1 );
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1 );
        background: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #f1f1f1 );
    }
```

And here is the javascript:

```
        function show_about(x){
        var about = document.getElementById(x), h = "auto";
        // or 
        // var menu = this.children[0];  

        if(about.style.height == h){
            about.style.height = "0px";
        }else{
            about.style.height = h;         
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think the transition will not work with `auto`. try % or px values.

Comment: Classic solution to this problem is to transition on `max-height`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Which_CSS_properties_are_animatable.3F):

> Also the `auto` value is often a very complex case. The specification asks not to animate from and to such a value. Some user agents, like those based on Gecko, implement this requirement and others, like those based on WebKit, are less strict. Using animations with `auto` may lead to unpredictable results, depending of the browser and its version, and should be avoided.